# XSD that allows attributes on elements in a sequence

Tags: xml

I want to create an XSD schema that will permit the following XML.  I think I have everything except for the attribute on the `<subsegent>` element.  Can some one provide a sample XSD?  Everything I've tried produces an error.

```
<Segment>
    <Subsegment target="all">This is test 1</Subsegment>
    <Subsegment target="some">This is test 2</Subsegment>
</Segment>
```

UPDATE

Here is one XSD I tried.  I want the elements within the sequence to have attributes.  I get this error: "The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:attribute' element is not supported in this context." from my tool.

thanks

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
<xsd:complexType name="Segment">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Subsegment" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:attribute name="target" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Show us what you've got so far. Then (a) it's less work for us to answer than starting from scratch, and (b) we can see where you went wrong so we can explain your mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema....

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:element name="Segment">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Subsegment" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="SubsegmentType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="SubsegmentType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="target" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

And the results using xmllint....

```
xmllint testfile.xml --schema Subsegment.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Segment>
    <Subsegment target="all">This is test 1</Subsegment>
    <Subsegment target="some">This is test 2</Subsegment>
</Segment>
testfile.xml validates
```

Let's add some errors to verify...

**Using an unspecified element**

```
xmllint badtestfile.xml --schema Subsegment.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Segment>
    <Something-Else/>
    <Subsegment target="all">This is test 1</Subsegment>
    <Subsegment target="some">This is test 2</Subsegment>
</Segment>
badtestfile.xml:3: element Something-Else: Schemas validity error : Element 'Something-Else': This element is not expected. Expected is ( Subsegment ).
badtestfile.xml fails to validate
```

**Using an invalid attribute**

```
xmllint badtestfile.xml --schema Subsegment.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Segment>
    <Subsegment mytarget="all">This is test 1</Subsegment>
    <Subsegment target="some">This is test 2</Subsegment>
</Segment>
badtestfile.xml:3: element Subsegment: Schemas validity error : Element 'Subsegment', attribute 'mytarget': The attribute 'mytarget' is not allowed.
badtestfile.xml fails to validate
```